# How to add an external page in smarty

Tags: php, smarty

I need to add a report page in smarty. I need to create an external page to get report. How can i get smarty predefined variables, database configuration file and class files in external page. Can anyone help, thanks in advance.

Comment: You want to apply your database configuration file to the external page ?

Comment: Yes Sulthan, but i need to check whether the user logged in or not and then i need to use the library functions.

Comment: You want to help me in `file_get_contents` ?

Comment: I am not sure but i need to check the user login and make use of smarty library functions. can u help me..?

Comment: sure, that external page is outside your domain ?

Comment: No, i have that page in that same directory. I am using it in my localhost.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the class of smarty for the external say `somefile.php` file by

```
include('Smarty.class.php');
$smarty = new Smarty;
// your declarations here
//your db connection and get your predefined variable using include
$smarty->display('somefile.tpl');
```

And in the `somefile.tpl` file you will get it by  `{$declared variable}`

So, Whenever you run the file somefile.php you can able to get the values inside it.

Comment: Thanks Sulthan.. I will try it.. Can u give any example to check if the user logged in or not..?

Comment: Try and let me know if you need any help in it :)

Comment: I tried but it showing errors for  every predefined variables.. Is it possible to access all predefined variables in smarty..?